# можно ли изменить ключи объекта?

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30
};
==>
user{a:"John", b:"30"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно удалить старые ключи и добавить новые

```js
let user = { name: 'John', age: 30 };
// Добавляем новые
user.a = 'John';
user.b = '30';
// Удаляем старые
delete user.name;
delete user.age;

console.log(user);
```